# JMS Outbound Gateway request destination - post process on success

Tags: spring-integration, spring-java-config

I am using a `JMS Outbound Gateway` to send messages to a request queue and receive messages from a separate response queue. I would like to add functionality so that a call is made to a specific bean's method once a message has been successfully sent to the request queue.

I am using `spring-integration 4.0.4` APIs and `spring-integration-java-dsl 1.0.0` APIs for this and, I have so far been able to achieve the above functionality as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("request.ch")
            .routeToRecipients(r ->
                r.ignoreSendFailures(false)
                 .recipient("request.ch.1", "true")
                 .recipient("request.ch.2", "true"))
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sendReceiveFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("request.ch.1")
            .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(cachingConnectionFactory)
                    .receiveTimeout(45000)
                    .requestDestination("REQUEST_QUEUE")
                    .replyDestination("RESPONSE_QUEUE")
                    .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID"), e -> e.requiresReply(true))
                    .channel("response.ch").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow postSendFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("request.ch.2")
            .handle("requestSentService", "fireRequestSuccessfullySentEvent")
            .get();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, although the above configuration works, I have noticed that the only apparent reason `request.ch.1` is called before `request.ch.2` seems to be because of the channel names' alphabetical order and not because of the order in which they where added to the `RecipientListRouter` itself. Is this correct? Or am I missing something here?

*** EDIT below shows solution using Aggregator between JMS Outbound/Inbound Adapters approach (without Messaging Gateway) ***

Integration Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig { 

    ...

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow reqFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("request.ch")
            .enrichHeaders(e -> e.headerChannelsToString())
            .enrichHeaders(e -> e.headerExpression(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID, "headers['" + MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL + "']"))             
            .routeToRecipients(r -> {
                r.ignoreSendFailures(false);
                r.recipient("jms.req.ch", "true");
                r.recipient("jms.agg.ch", "true");
            })
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsReqFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("jms.req.ch")
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory)
                    .destination("TEST_REQUEST_CH")).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsPostReqFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("jms.req.ch")
            .handle("postSendService", "postSendProcess")
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsResFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory).destination(
                    "TEST_RESPONSE_CH"),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(10)))
            .channel("jms.agg.ch").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsAggFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("jms.agg.ch")
            .aggregate(a -> { 
                a.outputProcessor(g -> {
                    List<Message<?>> l = new ArrayList<Message<?>>(g.getMessages());

                    Message<?> firstMessage = l.get(0);
                    Message<?> lastMessage = (l.size() > 1) ? l.get(l.size() - 1) : firstMessage;

                    Message<?> messageOut = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(lastMessage)
                            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, (String) firstMessage.getHeaders().getReplyChannel())
                            .build();

                     return messageOut;
                }); 
                a.releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() == 2);
                a.groupTimeout(45000);
                a.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(false);
                a.discardChannel("jms.agg.timeout.ch");
            }, null)
            .channel("response.ch")
            .get();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsAggTimeoutFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("jms.agg.timeout.ch")
            .handle(Message.class, (m, h) -> new ErrorMessage(new MessageTimeoutException(m), h))
            .channel("error.ch")
            .get();
    }
}
```

Cheers,
PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H-m... Looks like. It is really a bug in the `DslRecipientListRouter` logic: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/9
Will be fixed soon and released over a couple of days.

Thank you for pointing that out!

BTW. your logic isn't correct a bit: Even when we fix that `RecipientListRouter`, the second recipinet will receive the same request message only after `JmsOutboundGateway` will have received the `reply`, not just after request has been sent to the request-queue.
It is blocked request-reply process. And there is no a hook to get a point between reqeust and reply in the `JmsOutboundGateway`.

Is that OK for you?

Comment: I'll give the release with fix a go when available. With regards to your mention of logic: When I first implemented this functionality, I had a configuration where `request.ch` was a pub-sub channel with only `sendReceiveFlow()` and `postSendFlow()` feeding off that pub-sub channel. With that configuration I had the behaviour that you describe but, with the configuration shown in this post, it seems the `postSendFlow()` is only called when message has been successfully sent to request queue and before message is received from response queue. I'll run a test tomorrow and double-check this...

Comment: Alongside with the recipinetList `order` fix, there have been added other improvements, like `.recipient("request.ch.1")` and `.recipient(myChannel())`. Another feature is the `requiresReply = true` by default for those `outboundGateway`s which are do similar in the XML configuration. So, with this fix your code can be simplified a bit.

Comment: I finally had a chance to run a test and yes, the `postSendFlow()` is definitely not getting called when I thought it would. Are there any alternatives to make this work? If I were to for example use a `JmsOutboundAdapter` and a JmsInboundAdapter` instead of a `JMS Outbound Gateway`, could I still apply a 45 second reply timeout rule for response messages?

Comment: As I said: any outbound-gateway is a black-box and we can't hook between request and reply. If you'd use a couple of Inboud- and OutboundAdapters you should do the correlation manually and... use aggregator behind the gateway to achieve `reply-timeout`.

Comment: Hello @Artem, sorry for delay in replying. Been sidetracked with other work + hols and only getting back to this now! Anyway, I had a look at using an aggregator as you suggested and couldn't quite figure out (with little reading) how to apply it in this situation. I am however trying another approach (which I am hoping you can tell me if it's sensible?). How about if I configure a pair of JMS Outbound/Inbound Adapters behind a simple messaging Gateway? That way, I can set the reply timeout on the Gateway before the JMS send/receive parts? I'll Edit main question thread to show this.

Comment: Without an aggregator for request and reply as a group to release you can't achieve the Gateway `TemporaryReplyChannel` correlation. You just send a request to the `outbound` adapter and to the aggregator. The `inbound` adapter should send its result to the aggregator with the same `correlationKey` to group the result and return it to the reply for the Gateway.

Comment: Oh, I've just edited the main post to show the JMS adapters behind a simple gateway approach. But you are saying that approach would still not work?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Because Gateway's reply relies on the `TemporaryReplyChannel` and blocking for the calling Thread. There is `<header-channels-to-string>`, of course, but I'm not sure that you will be able to transport it to the JMS and back. However you can try... Otherwise you should get deal with aggregator for request/reply pair and publish-subscribe for the request to send to JMS and to the aggregator.

Comment: I have run a some messaging test scenarios using JMS Adapter(s) behind a simple Messaging Gateway approach and so far the tests have all passed. My tests included: 1) send one request expecting one response back, 2) send one request expecting NO response back (causing Gateway to time out after 45secs), 3) send multiple requests expecting multiple responses back, 4) send multiple requests expecting NO responses back (causing Gateway to time out after 45secs for each passed request). All tests passeds. To clarify, multiple reqs flow through separate threads (using xN Thread executor pool).

Comment: That's true, because you use `e.headerChannelsToString()` and it does the stuff for those `TemporaryReplyChannel` per Thread. And looks like your JSM stuff correctly transport those headers over request/reply. So, does that mean we fixed your requirements?

Comment: Following on from this, I am now not sure which approach to finally take. Aggregator approach or JMS Adapter(s) behing Messaging Gateway approach! The reason I want to ensure to get this right is that we are in the process of proofing the general EIP patterns that we will be using for each and all EIP flows across our enterprise and we want to: a) make sure the flows behave as we expect, and b) the flows are as self-explanatory as possible for ease of documentation afterwards (this being the reason why I am trying to avoid the aggregator approach in this area of EIP flow behaviour).

Comment: My tests do seem to show it does work so I would say yes, the requirement has been met! Unless you think there may be other test scenarios I've missed that I should also check?

Comment: It won't work if other side remove your required `replyChannel` header. In this case it will be treated as `Gateway to time out after 45secs`. That's why `aggregator` solution to correlate reqeust and reply for adapter pair is more robust.

Comment: I understand what you are saying now, yes. We have no guarantees that the `replyChannel` message header will be preserved outside of our domain, understood. I will have a go at using the `Aggregator` approach and re-run the test scenarios. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, I have now implemented solution using `Aggregator` as suggested by @Artem. See main EDIT. Note that I have removed the need for a `Messaging Gateway` altogether and instead the `Aggregator` itself is now taking care of the 45sec timeout requirement (This way the `Aggregator` can clear up partial groups when timeouts occur). All our functional tests are passing okay with this solution but I wouldn't mind to know whether the `Aggregator` solution shown in the main EDIT is as good as it can be, or whether there are any improvements that could be made to it?

Comment: Yes, there are many places which can be improved, but if it is worked for, I'd say let's go ahead with business logic! Right now I'd like to see the approve to my answer

Comment: Here are comments to your solution: https://gist.github.com/artembilan/9ffba1bb0b18842e27cf

Comment: Thanks for the suggested improvements. I have now EDITed the Aggregator based solution to reflect these.